# omitting the definite article before "of"

Tags: articles

Generally in "of phrases' the definite article is used. For example:

> Mike has the charm of a good artist.

Although "charm" is an uncountable noun, it is defined by "an artist", so it must take the article. But I have come across some uncountable nouns, which are too modified in a way, which do not require using " the".
For example:

> Robert has control of Mike.
>   Kate has command of English.

Is there any way to feel or work out when articles should be omitted?

Comment: A person is a  person. X has control of [**a** or **the** person], of John, of Mike. And "Kate has command of the English" would make Kate a field commander or military person.

Comment: You're simply mistaken if you think *"charm" is [**always**] an uncountable noun*. In your specific context it *can't* be uncountable, because it's preceded by the definite article ***the***. This pragmatically implies there must be *other* [types of] charm besides the kind that good artists have, which clearly doesn't match the definition [*uncountable nouns are substances, concepts etc that we cannot divide into separate elements.*](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-countable-un.htm) It would be different in, say, *Mike has charm,* but that's not the same construction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Following your logic, **the water** in the sentence _The water in the lake was clean and cool_ is countable, isn't it? I doubt that— _The water in the lake**s** was clean and cool_.

Comment: These comments are way over the head of someone who doesn't speak English well.

Comment: @Lambie OP is wondering about these possibilities: ***Robert has the control of Mike. Kate has the command of English.***

Comment: @MvLog Sure seems countable to me: the water in lake 1, the water in lake 2, etc.

Comment: @BobRodes    Then **they** should be **the waterS in the lakes** which is not the case.

Comment: @Mv Log: Uncountable: *We believe water is essential for life*. Countable: *The water in this lake is clean, but the water in that lake is dirty (they're **different waters**).*

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I didn't ask you about two lakes. My question was whether **the water** in the sentence _The water in the lake was clean and cool_ is countable or not. According to your statement: **In your specific context it can't be uncountable, _because_ it's preceded by the definite article the** an occurrence of **the** before an uncountable noun turns it into countable. I doubt it and consider _the water_ in my example as still uncountable regardless of **the**.

Comment: @MvLog No, it isn't the case. But it isn't the case that *water* has to be plural for it to be countable either, since I counted it. If it looks like a duck, quacks like a duck and all that. As for your response to FumbleFingers, since the water is in the lake, it is qualified in such a way that it can be counted; QED with my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you use the definite article in "Mike has the charm of a good artist" is because you are specifying the charm that Mike has, rather than charm in general. It's not countable, but it is still specified which charm.

A very commonly used version of this use is "the voice of an angel." 
You can say "Mike has charm" (an unspecified amount or type) too.

You could actually say "Kate has the command of English," or "Robert has the command of Mike," but to my ear it would sound like you are describing a temporary situation rather than a general sense of relationship.

Comment: You are wrong—neither **has control of** nor **has command of** is a phrasal verb. In both cases the words after **has** are nouns. Moreover, there is no explanation in your answer just tautology.